# Making a guessing program, need it to remember if I have guessed that number

Tags: java, arrays, memory

I am making a simple guessing program. Guess the number 1-20, if you get it wrong, it *should* not print that number ever again. It is still doing that however, and I need help figuring out how to make it remember that.

Please do not berate me, I am new to programming. =)

Here is the code friends:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TG_UN5EX5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int characternumber = 0;

        int characterrandom = (int) (Math.random() * (100 + 1 - 1) + 1);

        int[] list = new int[20];

        int e = 0;

        int random = (int) (Math.random() * (20 - 1 + 1) + 1);

        int guesstimes = 5;

        int guess = 0;

        int guessed = 0;

        while (guess != random && guesstimes > 0) {
            for (int b = 0; b < list.length; b++) {
                e++;
                list[b] = e;

                if (guess == e)
                    list[e] = -1;
                if (e >= 20)
                    e = 0;

                if (list[e] != -1)
                    System.out.print("[" + list[b] + "] ");
            }

            System.out.print("What is the number?");
            guess = scan.nextInt();

            if (guess > random)
                System.out.println("Too High!");

            else if (guess < random)
                System.out.println("Too Low!");

            else
                System.out.println("You got it!");

            guesstimes--;
        }

        if (guess != random)
            System.out.println("Game over! \n You ran out of tries!");

        else
            System.out.println("You won!");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your arrays with Set's. They will help you keep track of previous guesses with methods like .contains(). Use the Integer object rather than the int primitive when setting the type of your Set.

```
final Set<Integer> guesses = new HashSet<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize your variable list just after you declared it:

```
int[] list = new int[20];
for (int b = 0; b < list.length; b++) {
 list[b] = b+1; 
}
```

And then rewrite your for loop to:

```
for (int b = 0; b < list.length; b++) {
 if (guess == list[b]) 
    list[b] = -1; 
if (list[b] != -1) 
    System.out.print("[" + list[b] + "] "); }
```